# How to authenticate an AWS Web app with a .NET Core API hosted in Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

We have a .NET Core 6 API hosted in Azure and protected by Azure AD (Microsoft Entra ID). Another team is planning to deploy a web application in AWS which needs to call the API hosted in Azure. In Azure app registrations, we can specify authorized client apps for web applications hosted in Azure. Is this possible to do machine-to-machine authentication or set up application permissions for an AWS resource to call an Azure resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have accomplished this and the implementation was easier than I was originally anticipating. An application registration is required in Azure, for the host in AWS. The registration does not care where the host is deployed. When the AWS resource requests a token for the Azure tenant, a POST request is made to the tenant token endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

with the following payload

```
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: my_app_client_id
client_secret: my_app_client_secret
scope: scope_for_api_i_want_to_call
```

Retrieving the token then passing it to the API works.